# Parsing various parts of JSON file from URL to use with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapbox

I'm trying to Parse a part of the JSON to use with Mapbox.
Here is an example of a JSON file:

```
{
  "time":"06:00",
  "location": [
    {
      "device_id": "019823123123123",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "point",
        "coordinates": [
          -4.19635681,
          20.19492493,
          -12.282
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is a part of the code:

```
    async function getLocation(updateSource) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://localhost/data.json', {
        method: 'GET'
      }
    );

    const {
    
      coordinates // <<--- THIS IS MY PROBLEM, HOW DO I FETCH THIS PART OF JSON?
      
      // var longitude = location[1].geometry.coordinates[0] <<--- I ALSO TRIED THIS BUT NOT LUCK
      // var latitude = location[1].geometry.coordinates[1] <<--- I ALSO TRIED THIS BUT NOT LUCK
      
    } = await response.json()


        map.flyTo({
                    center: [longitude, latitude], // <<-- AND CONVERT IT TO THIS FORM?
                    essential: true


                });
```

How do I put an array of coordinates into separate longitude/latitude?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you but none of the above answers worked, I got it to work with the following code:

```
const response = await fetch(
                
                    'http://localhost/data.json', {
                        method: 'GET'
                    })

                const results = await response.json()

                const longitude = results.locations[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
                const latitude = results.locations[0].geometry.coordinates[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

`location` is an array of one object which has a `geometry` property, which has a co-ordinates property which is an array, and you just need the first two elements of that array.

```js
const response = {
  "time":"06:00",
  "location": [
    {
      "device_id": "019823123123123",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "point",
        "coordinates": [
          -4.19635681,
          20.19492493,
          -12.282
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

const {
  location: [
    {
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [ lat, lng ]
      }
    }
  ]
} = response;

console.log(lat, lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save the result in a variable/constant and then traverse to the `coordinates` array:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost/data.json', {method: 'GET'})
const result = await response.json()

const coordinates = result.location[0].geometry.coordinates
```

Also, you may need to use the `coordinates` to get `latitude` and `longitude` in this ways:

```
const [latitude, longitude] = coordinates;
// or
const latitude = coordinates[0]
const loingitude = coordinates[1]
```

the `location` array in your response may contain several **objects** with different `coordinates` and you will use `map` function to do something with the result:

```
const locations = result.location // get the location array

const newArrayOfLocations = locations.map(location => (
 {
  center: [location.geometry.coordinates[0], location.geometry.coordinates[1]],
  essential: true
 })
)
```

You can also use array destruction in the `map` function:

```
locations.map(location => {
 const [latitude, longitude] = location.geometry.coordinates

 return {
  center: [latitude, longitude],
  essential: true
 }}
)
```